# sed regular expression for escaped urls

Tags: linux, sed

why is `sed` not replacing anything:

```
sed -i '' 's/<a href="\.\.\/\.\.\/ja\/%E6%9C%88\/[^-]\+-page-[\d]\+.html"\/>//g' foo.htm
```

I want it to match the following string:

```
<a href="../../ja/%E6%9C%88/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AE%E3%83%A9-page-2013.html"/>
```

Comment: some observations: `sed` doesn't support `\d` ... use `[0-9]`... and even `GNU sed` which supports sequences like `\w`, `\s` etc won't work inside character class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `\d` to match digits with sed. Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`:

```
sed -i '' 's/<a href="\.\.\/\.\.\/ja\/%E6%9C%88\/[^-]\+-page-[0-9]\+.html"\/>//g' foo.htm
```

Comment: the suggested command still does not work. It seems like `[^-]\+` is the problem...

Comment: `\+` is a GNU sed extension. You can have the same result with  `[^-]\{1,\}` or `[^-][^-]*`.